# QGIS desktop windows lacking annotation tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am fairly new to QGIS. I created a QGIS project with a country map and some annotations on it. When I open it in QGIS I cannot see the annotation tool option on the toolbar. I need to edit the annotations and it seems impossible without the annotation toolbar. I have tried enabling and renabling all toolbars but it's still not visible. Online documentation show this as a icon with a small T on it.

[image]

Comment: Pleasen add the screenshot to you question and not only a link.

Comment: Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbWGM.png